# How to enforce a http 403 or 404?

Tags: php

Is it possible to kind of force a 403 or 404 error?

I have a kind of admin page, where I am trying to prevent hackers from getting into my filesystem on my server. (the path get's delivered over the url and it would be possible to just pass a ../ into it and get up in my filestructure - I know that's not a good thing to do it). Anyway If somebody tries to enter a ../ into my url I am currently just using a die('forbidden') to make sure that this area on my server is forbidden.

I was wondering now if it's actually possible to kind of fire a real forbidden 403 error? I've defined a 403 page in my .htaccess document which shows up if it's a real 403. Is it possible to kind of fire a 403 so that the .htaccess links to the 403 page. I mean I could easily hardcode it and simply link to the 403 error page. I just wondered if this is possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just issue

```
header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
```

before *any* other output.

Also make sure you double, and triple check your path sanitizer.

Comment: And remember to call exit() afterwards. It's no use if you send a 403 forbidden header but have the actual page as payload ...

Comment: Any reason you use HTTP 1.0 instead of 1.1?

Comment: There is no particular reason. This is just the simplest example.

Answer (score 6):

This will send a 404 and also include your 404 page:

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
include("/var/www/html/site.domain.com/err/404.php"); 
?>
```

Source: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/784.htm (from google)